# When is a function one-to-one?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

I am going crazy over a statement that is supposed to be false.

"A function T: R^n -> R^m is one-to-one if the only vector v in R^n whose image is 0 is v = 0"

I thought this was true since otherwise if there was another vector u that did not equal the zero vector but whose image was the zero vector then f(u) and f(v) would not be distinct and hence the function not one-to-one. This also explains why the null space consisting of only the zero vector makes the function one-to-one. For if in the RREF there were free variable(s) then the generating set for the null space would not only be the zero vector. Multiple vectors of R^n would equal the zero vector of R^m and hence the function would not be one-to-one.

Where does my logic break?

Comment: Do you talk about arbitrary functions or *linear* functions?

Comment: It doesnt specify, it states only what i wrote. I was actually wondering if it was a trick question and the book left it ambiguous on purpose. However in terms of the section and chapter that i am on, it is about linear functions/linear transformations.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of being one to one is: *if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$*.

This definition is for **functions**. The statement you are posting don't work for functions in general, it's works for a special kind of functions called **linear** (maybe **linear transformation** in your case). Then

*If $T$ is just a function*: this is false. Take $T:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $T(0)=0$ and $T(x)=1$ if $x\neq 0$.

*If $T$ is linear*: this is true. Suppose that the unique vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $T(\mathbf{v})=0$ is $\mathbf{v}=0$. If $T(\mathbf{v})=T(\mathbf{w})$ then $T(\mathbf{v})-T(\mathbf{w})=0$, so $T(\mathbf{v-w})=0$ which implies $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{w}$ and $T$ is one to one. The other direction is clear.

Comment: How does your explanation of T not being linear function with T(0)=0 and T(x)=1 where x!=0 explains why T is not one-to-one. Shouldnt you try to show something along the lines of a none linear function T where T(0)=0 and T(x)=0 where x!=0? Also it would help to give an example of such a function T.

Comment: @Bubbletea He's trying to point out that for non-linear functions, the condition "$T(x)=0$ has only the solution $x =0$" is not enough to prove one-to-one-ness. So he needs a function that _fulfills that condition_, but still isn't one-to-one. Therefore, for $T$ to be a true example of what he wants to show, $T(x)$ has to be something other than $0$ (say, for instance $1$) when $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Now it depends on the definition of *one-to-one*. For me *one-to-one* means that
the mapping is injective **and** surjective. So $T: R \to R^2, x\mapsto (x,0)$ would not be *one-to-one* in this definition.

Since it is said in a comment that this does not answer the question: The question is why a -- I guess linear -- mapping from $R^m$ to $R^n$ can be not one-to-one if only the zero vector is mapped into the zero vector. If an one-to-one correspondence is meant as I suppose here, it gives an example and answers the question.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one), a one-to-one _function_ is injective, while a one-to-one _correspondence_ is bijective. Not that wikipedia decides the standard in any way, but I think that's the common interpretation.

Comment: @Arthur, ok,  but then the statement the OP asks about, would be true, or? I would say, here it depends on the *exact wording* and the used definitions.

Comment: And you're right that knowing the exact definitions is important to answering this question, but that would make this answer more suited as a comment (it does not answer the question, it asks for clarification).